# Different computers with Windows 8 with the same account

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, taskbar, themes

I've got several systems set up with Windows 8 in my home.
1 is my desktop with a triple screen setup and I like having the taskbar vertically on the left edge of the left monitor. Also, I like having nice wallpapers with some women or other NSFW images.

The second is my development laptop, which is a single screen (sometimes dual screen) setup. On this machine I like having my taskbar at the bottom of the primary display and having some 'decent' wallpapers.

I've configured most of these settings in different Themes (I think all of this this is stored in themes).

The problem is when I set up a theme on 1 machine, the other machine synchronizes and updates it's theme also. Therefore I have to manually set up the theme again & re-adjust the taskbar.

Can I fix this 'intelligent' synchronizing system, so it knows on which system I am and doesn't update it?

Comment: You can choose which settings you will share.  You can also disable syncing all together.  How you do this is documented on Microsoft website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can selectively choose which settings to be synced. Open charms bar (Win+C) and select `Settings` and then `Change PC settings` in the bottom. Now select `Sync your settings` tab to view what is being synced. You can turn the slider off on `Desktop Personalization` to prevent themes and taskbar from being synced.

Comment: Thanks, would have never found this. BTW, the `Sync your settings` resides in the `OneDrive` menu.